# how to add user and login with google oauth

Tags: google-oauth, apache-superset

Im trying to add google oauth2 as my login method in superset. Users cant register by their own, the system admin must provide access for the user deppending on permissions/role.

When a annonymous user loged in, the system must check if the user email exist and what role is applied to him and show the user profile

I already have the google oauth2 linked in superset, i can click in the login google button the login pop apears and enter the email and pasword of an google acount. But when the login is done, it apears a message saying that the user is not authorized.

[Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CT1B.png)

[After Login, with console error (page stays loading...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hotR.png)

The question is how i can associate an google user to a superset user, or register an user by this google oauth2 method with the respective role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is set Flask App Builder's `AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True` and 
`AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "some_default_role"`.

Then if you want to alter the registration flow, I'd recommend setting your own SecurityManager and overriding `BaseSecurityManager.auth_user_oauth` . I'd copy the source of that method and alter it.

I'd be great if FAB had a pre_registration hook in `BaseSecurityManager` for this purpose. Maybe it could receive the `User` object FAB is planning on creating (before it gets created) and could return a list of roles, or `None` if we want to abort the registration process.

Comment: can i set the CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER as my  CustomSecurityManager to override BaseSecurityManager.auth_user_oauth in superset_config?

Comment: Yes that is the way to do it.